# Cannot read property '_location' of null with Jest on Firebase auth in a create-react-app application

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, jestjs, create-react-app

I created a new application with create-react-app 0.8.5.
I want to test firebase authentification with Jest like that :

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
describe('Firebase', function() {
    it('auth succeed', () => {
        const config = {  
            apiKey: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            authDomain: "XXXXXXXXXXXX.firebaseapp.com",
            databaseURL: "https://XXXXXXXXXXXX.firebaseio.com",
            storageBucket: "XXXXXXXXXXXX.appspot.com",
            messagingSenderId: "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY"
        };
        const database = firebase  
            .initializeApp(config)
            .database()
            .ref();
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword("toto@mail.com", "zzzzzz").catch(function(error) {
            fail("Auth error");
        });
    });
});
```

But i obtain that error :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '_location' of null
    at Window.location (D:\...\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\browser\Window.js:147:79)
    at callback [as _onTimeout] (D:\...\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\browser\Window.js:479:40)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:92:15)
 npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

Have you any clue to explain that ?
Is there any way to have more log on that error ?

Comment: I succeed to pass the test by remove "--env=jsdom" in package.json : 
"test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",

Comment: I also am getting this error, and it still (or again?) appears to be an outstanding issue in jest https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/10311